# df.groupby('MONTH')['TASKTYPE'].value_counts().unstack().loc[month_order].plot.bar(stacked=True) - KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I am trying to plot data which looks like this:

```
MONTH TASKTYPE
09/19 A
09/19 B
10/19 B
10/19 B
01/20 A
```

`MONTH`is a column which contains strings. When I now plot this data using this code:

```
df.groupby('MONTH')['TASKTYPE'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

I get the data ordered by lexicographical order. Instead I would like to order it chronologically and therefore created a list:

```
month_order = ['09/19','10/19','01/20']
```

I tried to use `month_order` and plot my data:

```
df.groupby('MONTH')['TASKTYPE'].value_counts().unstack().loc[month_order].plot.bar(stacked=True,figsize=(12,8))
```

But got this error code:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['09/19', '10/19', '01/20' dtype='object', name='MONTH')] are in the [index]"
```

How should I amend my code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, convert it to datetimes:

```
df['MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MONTH'], format='%m/%y', errors='coerce')
```

Or to months periods:

```
df['MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MONTH'], format='%m/%y', errors='coerce').dt.to_period('m')
```

before your solution.

So all together:

```
df['MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MONTH'], format='%m/%y').dt.to_period('m')
df.groupby('MONTH')['TASKTYPE'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get: `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  `

Comment: @Tobitor - So it is possible some datetimes are wrong? Do you need replace them to NaTs by `df['MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MONTH'], format='%m/%y', errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: I found it. There was a blank space included. :-) Thank you very much!